# JakartaVelocity 1.7 form submission with Spring MVC, getting null values in controller

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, velocity

I am generating a form from velocity and submitting the form values to spring controller. in the spring controller i am getting "null" values.

Form: test.vm, on submit calling controller with @RequestMapping /testform with post method

```
<html>
  <body>
  <form method="POST" action="/testform">
  Select testtype:
  <select name="test">
  <option value="test1">test1</option> 
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value ="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>

Controller code:

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testform", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ModelAndView addtest(@ModelAttribute("test")ReadTest test, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("in test controller");

    System.out.println("test:" + test.gettest());
    return new ModelAndView("test");
}
```

ReadTest.java is java class with getters.

```
public class ReadTest {
public String test;
public String gettest() {
return test;
```

}
}

After submit the form values, test.gettest() in controller returning 'null'
Can you help where I am doing wrong? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add commandName = "test". It like as:

```
<form method="POST" action="/testform" commandName ="test">
```

Comment: Thanks, b/w, what is test here? is the name defined in @ModelAttribute("test") ?

Comment: Still I see null values in cotroller, commandName attribute didn't solve my problem, also tried with modelAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to add command name for it like

```
<form method="POST" commandname="test" action="/testform">
```

As well as i think you are missing the settters in the ReadTest.java.Please add the setters and check once.
Please refer to this [link](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-handling/) once for example code.